# Ошибки при установке symfony

Tags: php, symfony

После ввода:

```
sudo composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

Выводит:

```
[RuntimeException]
  Could not load package symfony/website-skeleton in http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse
   version constraint ^7.0.8: Invalid version string "^7.0.8"
[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint ^7.0.8: Invalid version string "^7.0.8"
```

Comment: Зачем sudo? Какой версии композер? Скорее всего надо обновить его.

Comment: Composer version 1.0.0-alpha8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обновите composer: [composer sef-update](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate-). Или если ставили из пакетного менеджера, то с помощью пакетного менеждера (например: `sudo apt-get upgrade composer`).

Comment: Спасибо большое!